# Loopback setting a property that somehow doesn't persist to the database sql?

Tags: loopbackjs

We're porting our api from C# to Loopback `^v3.19.0` and have run into a blocker.

Many of our models have shared properties, so we've created a base model "Base" which they inherit from.

```
{
  "name": "Base",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "mixins": {
    "Timestamp": {}
  },
  "properties": {   
    "created-by": {
      "type": "number",
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "created_by"
      }
    },
    "created-date": {
      "type": "date",
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "created_on_utc"
      }
    },
    "updated-by": {
      "type": "number",
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "updated_by"
      }
    },
    "updated-date": {
      "type": "date",
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "updated_on_utc"
      }
    },
    "soft-deleted": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "is_deleted"
      }
    },
    "deleted-by": {
      "type": "number",
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "deleted_by"
      }
    },
    "deleted-date": {
      "type": "date",
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "deleted_on_utc"
      }
    },
    "tenant-id": {
      "type": "number",
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "tenant_id"
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Inside the **Timestamp** mixin (our own), those properties get set accordingly

```
module.exports = function(Model, options) {
  Model.observe('before save', function event(ctx, next) {
    const token = ctx.options && ctx.options.accessToken;
    const userId = token && token.userId;
    const now = new Date().toISOString();

    if (ctx.instance) {
      ctx.instance['created-by'] = userId;
      ctx.instance['created-date'] = now;
      ctx.instance['updated-by'] = userId;
      ctx.instance['updated-date'] = now;
    } else {
      if (ctx.data['soft-deleted'] &&
          ctx.data['soft-deleted'] === true) {
        ctx.data['deleted-by'] = userId;
        ctx.data['deleted-date'] = now;
        ctx.data['is-active'] = false;
      }
      ctx.data['updated-by'] = userId;
      ctx.data['updated-date'] = now;
    }

    next();
  });
};
```

This works great when creating a new model. It *was* working great for updates `(PATCH /modelname/:id)`, but unexpectedly broke and we can't figure out why. (This is consistent across all the models that inherit from this `Base` model.)

The mixin correctly sees the model and adds the updated properties like so

```
LoopbackJS  | ************* 'before save' ctx.data **************
LoopbackJS  | { 'is-active': false,
LoopbackJS  |   'updated-by': 1,
LoopbackJS  |   'updated-date': '2018-08-16T17:57:23.660Z' }
LoopbackJS  | ************* END 'before save' ctx.data **************
```

But when loopback executes the update SQL, it somehow omits/removes the value for `updated-by`? (2nd param should be `1`, not `null`)

```
LoopbackJS  | 2018-08-16T17:57:23.666Z loopback:connector:postgresql SQL: UPDATE "public"."asset_types" SET "is_active"=$1,"updated_by"=$2,"updated_on_utc"=$3::TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,"tenant_id"=$4 WHERE "id"=$5
LoopbackJS  | Parameters: [false,null,"2018-08-16T17:57:23.660Z",1,5]
```

`updated_by` in Postgres is nullable, so that shouldn't generate an error... but Loopback is sending a stringified function?

```
LoopbackJS  | 2018-08-16T18:04:12.522Z loopback:connector:postgresql error: invalid input syntax for integer: "function () { [native code] }"
LoopbackJS  |     at Connection.parseE (/home/src/back-end/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:553:11)
LoopbackJS  |     at Connection.parseMessage (/home/src/back-end/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:378:19)
LoopbackJS  |     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/src/back-end/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:22)
LoopbackJS  |     at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
LoopbackJS  |     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:7)
LoopbackJS  |     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:12)
LoopbackJS  |     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:251:11)
LoopbackJS  |     at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
LoopbackJS  |     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:587:20)
```

If we don't touch the `updated_by` column, the SQL is correct and updates.

Incidentally, if we soft-delete and the `deleted_by` column is in play, the same thing happens there.

Feels like I'm spinning in circles here and probably overlooking something basic. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

So it appears that it's not limited to a mixin... when we remove it completely and manually set the k:v pair in the payload (ie `'created-by': 1`) we still get the same error back from Postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of this was due to incorrect relationships.

I created this [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/sacarino/9295ea09f020eee1b2274cd297cc4f22), but pasting it here too in case it helps someone else.

It's a `PostgreSQL` best-practice to use lowercase names, using snakecase if you need to. ie, *my_column_name*.

Also, since I'm using a [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) client, I've installed the **excellent** [loopback-component-jsonapi](https://github.com/digitalsadhu/loopback-component-jsonapi) to handle the de/serialization stuff... but that just added additional complexities.

JSON API calls for dasherized property names. When you start with something like `my-property-name`, Loopback or the PostgreSQL driver (doesn't really matter) collapses the dasherized property down to `mypropertyname` by default.

This is bad... especially when you have an existing schema you're working with.

It's worse when you're working with relationships, because Loopback *also* appends the `id` suffix by default, so now you have issues unless you happen to have a `mypropertynameid` column.

#### An example

Let's say we have a `Customer` model. I needed endpoints that are lowercase (and dasherized, where applicable), so just change the plural to match here.

```
{ 
  "name": "Customer",
  "plural": "customers",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
   ...
 }
```

Inside of `options.postgresql`, you can set a `tableName`. Loopback will use the `name`  value by default, but remember PostgreSQL doesn't like CamelCase. You need to override this unless you use lowercase model names.

*(It's a religious preference, but I like my tables to be plurals. Fight me.)*

```
{ 
  ...
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "postgresql": {
      "tableName": "customers"
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Back to the properties, use the `postgresql.columnName` property to map to the correct column name in the db. If it's not a dasherized property name (ie *`status`*) then you can ignore the `postgresql.columnName` bit.

```
{ 
  ...
  "properties": {
    "is-active": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": false,
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "is_active"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Relationships can be a headache.**

Let's say our `Customer` has people who work there. To do a basic one-many relationship between the models...

```
{ 
  ...
  "relations": {
    "people": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Person",
      "foreignKey": "customer_id"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

`people` is the name of the relationship element of the JSON API payload.

**A "gotcha" here for me was the `foreignKey` property.**

The Loopback docs say it's optional - and it is - but if you leave it out then it adds the `id` suffix to the name (`people`) and then looks for that column in your `customers` table. That wasn't highlighted very well, but it was clear enough.

*This part wasn't clear =>* I originally thought the `foreignKey` value pointed to the *property* of the `Person` model, so I had the dasherized `customer-id` property here. **That's incorrect.** It's literally asking you for the database column name, which feels like a bit of an antipattern... In the properties you had to define a `columnName` if you wanted to refer to the db columns under the ORM.

Also, note that the `foreignKey` property is reused in relationships but it means different things to different `type` contexts. In a `hasMany`, it's asking "Which column *there* maps to the primary key *here*?"

Final `Customer` model:

```
{ 
  "name": "Customer",
  "plural": "customers",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "postgresql": {
      "tableName": "customers"
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "is-active": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": false,
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "is_active"
      }
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "people": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Person",
      "foreignKey": "customer_id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

The `Person` model on the other end of the relationship.

The `foreignKey` for a `belongsTo` relationship is asking the opposite question... "Which property *here* maps to the primary key *there*?"

Also, if you have properties you don't want exposed (especially if you've inherited a model and don't want/need all those properties for whatever reason) then you can hide them with the `hidden` element. See below.

```
{
  "name": "Person",
  "plural": "people",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true,
    "postgresql": {
      "tableName": "people"
    }
  },
  "hidden": [
    "emailVerified",
    "realm",
    "username",
  ],
  "properties": {
    "first-name": {
      "type": "string",
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "first_name"
      }
    },
    "last-name": {
      "type": "string",
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "last_name"
      }
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    ...
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "customer": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Customer",
      "foreignKey": "customer_id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```